# Is this product and sum of integrals divisible by the polynomial $x^4$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Problem:**

> Let $A(t)$, $B(t)$, $C(t)$ and $D(t)$ be any polynomials with real
>   coefficients. Show that,

$F(x)$=[image]

> is divisible by $x^4$.

---

### **Proff:**

Before all, thanks LutzL for your clear explanation, here I put all the pieces together, to have a better understanding and to ask if I need to put some extra step in the proof explaining more, (I believe is fine, but I never sure). 
I put this symbol [] to inform that all was written by LutzL [“from LutzL comments and answer”].

> F(X)=

[image]

> This formula [‘has the form of a scalar product of two cross products
>   or the Cauchy-Binet formula which says that
>   (a×c,b×d)=(a,b)·(c,d)−(a,d)·(b,c)’]
>
> And the right, part [ ‘on the right you see the form of your given
>   term, on the left the components are (modulo signs)

[image]

> giving the scalar product,

[image]

> and we get;

[image]

> Now one has to explore the cancellation of lower-order terms. The integrand is a multiple of (s−t)^2  ds dt, which already accounts for the factor x^4. ]

[image]

> And then substitute s=xu , t=xv to get an equal form of the integral
>   of

**[image]

> The integrand is still a polynomial in u, v, x so that integration gives a polynomial in x as result. As for having two different integration variables, allows writing everything as one integral over a square.

[image]

In conclusion, from ** we can see that F(X)= (X^4 ) *  H(x) , where H(x) is the integral over the square. Therefore, F(x) is divisible by x^4.

**Question:** I need to explain, something else or is already a valid proof?
Again: Thanks, LutzL.

Comment: If $A,B,C,D$ are all constants then the integrals are the same, and the difference is zero (and so, divisible by $x^4$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can write the double of the term as
$$
\int_0^x\int_0^x (A(s)C(t)-A(t)C(s))·(B(s)D(t)-B(t)D(s))\,dsdt
$$
Now one has to explore the cancellation of lower-order terms. The integrand is a multiple of $(s-t)^2dsdt$, which already accounts for the factor $x^4$. More concretely, set 
$$
A(s)C(t)-A(t)C(s)=(s-t)P(s,t),\\ 
B(s)D(t)-B(t)D(s)=(s-t)Q(s,t)
$$
and then substitute $s=xu$, $t=xv$ to get an equal form of the integral of
$$
x^4·\int_0^1\int_0^1 (u-v)^2·P(ux,vx)·Q(ux,vx)\,dudv
$$

Comment: I like the grade of generality you use to make the proof , but it is difficult understand to me, what property you use in each step. Like first you write the problem with ds and dt using double integration, but I can't  see what propiety did you use; as well in the last part you write the integral using du and dv, and P(ux) Q(ux,vx). I belive I understand what you show, that the integrated (final) must be equal 1, after x^4/x^4 when x different than 0. Thanks so much for your time and your explanation.

Comment: Your formula has the form of a scalar product of two cross products or the Cauchy-Binet formula which says that $(a×c, \,b×d)=(a,b)·(c,d)-(a,d)·(b,c)$. On the right you see the form of your given term, on the left the components are (modulo signs) $(a×c)_{ij}=a_ic_j-a_jc_i$ for $i<j$ giving the scalar product $\frac12\sum_{i,j}(a_ic_j-a_jc_i)(b_id_j-b_jd_i)$. Now replace vectors by functions, Euclidean with Hilbert scalar products and you get my initial formula. (One could also just simply multiply it out.)

Comment: And in the last formula the integrand is still a polynomial in $u,v,x$ so that integration gives a polynomial in $x$ as result. As for having two different integration variables, $\int A(t)B(t)dt·\int C(t)D(t)dt=int A(s)B(s)ds·\int C(t)D(t)dt=\int \int A(s)B(s)·C(t)D(t)dsdt$ allows to write everything as one integral over a square.

Comment: I try to read more about the coefficient of the polynomials you posted, before editing your answer, but I can't not remember the correct name that you said time ago. Can you help my memory? Thanks, again.

Comment: The Bezoutian of two polynomials is the coefficient matrix of $\frac{P(X)Q(Y)-P(Y)Q(X)}{X-Y}$ as a symmetric form with the vectors $(1,X,X^2,…,X^d)$ and the same for $Y$. It can used to compute the resultant and is said to contain more information than the Sylvester matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I will write $A(t) = a_0 + a_1t + O(t^2)$, and the same for other polynomials. Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^x A(t)B(t) dt & = \int_0^x \left(a_0b_0 + (a_1b_0 + b_0b_1)t + O(t^2)\right) dt \\
& = a_0b_0x + \frac 12(a_1b_0 + a_0b_1)x^2 + O(x^3)
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \left(\int_0^x A(t)B(t)dt\right)\left(\int_0^x C(t)D(t)dt\right) \\
& \quad = a_0b_0c_0d_0x^2 + \frac 12(a_1b_0c_0d_0 + a_0b_1c_0d_0 + a_0b_0c_1d_0 + a_0b_0c_0d_1)x^3 + O(x^4).
\end{align}
It is obvious that permuting $(A, B, C, D)$ does not change the part with degrees lower than $4$.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to start by proving it for one term monic polynomials. Let $A(t)=t^a$ and so on.  Then $\int_0^x t^a dt=\frac {t^{a+1}}{a+1}$ and the whole expression becomes $$\left(\frac 1{(a+b+1)(c+d+1)}-\frac 1{(a+d+1)(b+c+1)}\right)x^{a+b+c+d+2}$$  If at least two of $a,b,c,d$ are positive, the exponent on $x$ is at least $4$.  If three of them are zero, the coefficient is zero. In either case we have the desired result.  Then show you can multiply any polynomial by a constant and it still works.  Now assume it has been proven for the combinations $a_1(t),B(t),C(t),(D(t)$ and $a_2(t),B(t),C(t),(D(t)$.  Show it still holds for $(a_1+a_2)(t),B(t),C(t),(D(t)$  by the linearity of the integral.  Now argue you can build up integrals of any complexity required by steps like this.